# An Inside View To One Thing Outside

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> You have seen me on the street
>   I am someone you try to meet
>   But I cut things as soon as I see them
>   Forming things before I meet them

What am I?

Comment: Does this depend on the streets of some specific locality/country or is it street in general?

Comment: Maybe a hint or some extra lines?

Comment: Something (I) peace or silence (II) gap between something in the road seems to fit very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a:

> Stranger's harsh gaze?

Seen on the street:

> People gaze at you on the street.

Try to meet:

> You meet the gaze of a stranger on the street.

Cut things as soon as I meet them:

> The owner of the gaze pierces and assumes things about the fellow stranger it meets.

Forming things before I meet them:

> The gaze (rather, the stranger controlling it) forms opinions.

This is the first time I've been proud of an answer I've posted on this site btw.

Comment: It's a good answer! It addresses most of the clues (except the title) and is well formatted. Nice work.

Comment: I'm not sure people are very enthusiastic about staring into a stranger's eyes.

Comment: Maybe nobody's enthusiastic about it, but ignoring them would be rude, right? I always meet the eyes of creepy folks, if only to be polite:P

Comment: These all fit. A stranger's gaze is, in short internalized, so that's how it also fits the title. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Traffic Light?

You have seen me on the street

> There's lots of you about!

I am someone you try to meet

> I try to meet you when you're green

But I cut things as soon as I see them

> Yes, your nasty red cuts my progress for other cars!

Forming things before I meet them

> Your orange is always busy collecting cars!

Answer (score 1):

Is it a:

> Garbage collector machine?

Because:

> They are collecting garbage on the streets. People sometimes go for it for pouring garbage stock.

Cut things:

> It cuts big pieces of garbage into small pieces.

Forming things before I meet them

> New things are made and after their usage, they are again pour into dustbin. For example, plastic cool drink bottle.